# unable to test component using highcharts w/ jasmine due to setInterval in async zone error

Tags: highcharts, angular, jasmine

I am trying to write a ng2 karma/jasmine test for a component that uses highcharts.  I'm using ng2 RC4 and current jasmine/karma.

It has an error (shown below, same error on both of the tests).  I appears that setInterval within a async zone is a no-go, but highcharts uses setInterval all over the place (one example shown below) & i'm not sure how to go about testing this component.

Does anyone have a link or info to how i should write this test?

```
Failed: Cannot use setInterval from within an async zone test.
Error: Cannot use setInterval from within an async zone test.
    at AsyncTestZoneSpec.eval [as _failCallback] (/Users//projects/g5-dashboard/dist/vendor/@angular/core/testing/async.js:34:38 <- ../../../../modules/@angular/core/testing/async.ts:37:27)
    at AsyncTestZoneSpec.onScheduleTask (/Users//projects/g5-dashboard/dist/vendor/zone.js/dist/async-test.js:93:23)
    at ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask (/Users//projects/g5-dashboard/dist/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:333:50)
    at Zone.scheduleMacroTask (/Users//projects/g5-dashboard/dist/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:273:40)
    at /Users//projects/g5-dashboard/dist/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1290:26
    at setInterval (eval at createNamedFn (/Users//projects/g5-dashboard/dist/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:982:18), <anonymous>:3:38)
    at Object.run (/Users//projects/g5-dashboard/dist/vendor/highcharts/highstock.src.js:240:33)
    at animate (/Users//projects/g5-dashboard/dist/vendor/highcharts/highstock.src.js:1385:16)
    at Object.animate (/Users//projects/g5-dashboard/dist/vendor/highcharts/highstock.src.js:2114:17)
    at Object.drawChartBox (/Users//projects/g5-dashboard/dist/vendor/highcharts/highstock.src.js:12985:26)
    at Object.redraw (/Users//projects/g5-dashboard/dist/vendor/highcharts/highstock.src.js:12266:23)
    at Object.update (/Users//projects/g5-dashboard/dist/vendor/highcharts/highstock.src.js:16464:23)
    at Object.setCategories (/Users//projects/g5-dashboard/dist/vendor/highcharts/highstock.src.js:16512:18)
    at BarChartComponent.reload_chart (/Users//projects/g5-dashboard/dist/app/shared_components/bar_chart.component.js:111:38
```

I'm testing the component like:

```
describe('InteractionBreakdownComponent', () => {
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<any>;
  let component: InteractionBreakdownComponent;

  beforeEach(() => {
    addProviders([
      { provide: Router, useClass: MockRouter },
      { provide: ReportsRouteParamService, useClass: MockParamsService },
      { provide: InteractionBreakdownService, useClass:          MockBreakdownReportService }
    ]);
  });

  beforeEach(async(inject([TestComponentBuilder], (tcb:  TestComponentBuilder) => {
    return tcb.createAsync(InteractionBreakdownComponent)
    .then((fix: ComponentFixture<any>) => {
       fixture = fix;
       component = fix.componentInstance;
    }, err => console.error(err));
  })));

  it('can be created', () => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('sets up params correct', () => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component.start_date).toBe('2015-06');
    expect(component.end_date).toBe('2015-09');
  });
   ...
```

Comment: Highcharts are using setInterval in their animations. You can disable animations by setting chart.animation and series.animation to false:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.animation
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.animation

Comment: This guy apparently solved it by returning promises...not sure that's even an acceptable workaround: https://github.com/angular/zone.js/issues/355